# Calling custom sails.js model from EJS template

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs, sails.js

How can I call custom model methods inside EJS-template? For example, let's say I have this model:

```
module.exports = {
    attributes = {
        bar: {
            type: 'string'
        },

        foo: function() {
            return 'It has got to be ' + this.bar;
        }
    }
};
```

Now, in my controller, I use passport.js to authenticate customer. After done, I want to store the user-model into session. This works, but I cannot access the custom methods tho:

```
module.exports = {
    login: function(req, res) {
        passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
            ...

            req.logIn(user, function(err) {
                req.session.user = user; // Has all the attributes, except functions.

                console.log(user.foo()); // Works!
            });
        })(req, res);
    }
};
```

But, as I said, this doesn't work in EJS template:

```
<%= user.foo() %>
```

but this will:

```
<%= user.bar %>
```

Why?

Comment: Calling model instance methods in a view should definitely work.  Can you show the part of your code that's calling the view?  What's happening when you try?